# why ajax.actionlink not refresh the page?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

First,sorry to my bad english.
I don't understand why my page not refresh when i click on the delete user...
After the click i check in database and the user is delete but my page with table not refresh, i dont't understand.

My views is:

```
@model IEnumerable<SiteWebEmpty.Models.User.UserDisplay>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.debug.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<h2>Display User</h2>
<div id="deleteUser">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table class="tabledisplayUser" border="1">
<tr>
<th>Name FirstName</th>
<th>UserName</th>
<th>Roles</th>
<th>Choice</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>@Html.Editor("name")</th>
<th>@Html.Editor("username")</th>
<th>@Html.Editor("roles")</th>
<th>@Html.Editor("choice")</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var user in Model)
{

    <tr>  
        <td class="action nameFirstName">@Html.DisplayFor(u => user.NameFirstName)</td>      
        <td class="action userName">@Html.DisplayFor(u => user.UserName)</td>
        @if (user.Roles.Roles.Count.Equals(0))
        {
            <td>Nobody Role</td>
        }
        else
        {
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("Roles", user.Roles.Roles)</td>    
        }
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { UserName = user.UserName }) | @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { UserName = user.UserName },
           new AjaxOptions()
           {
               HttpMethod = "POST",
               Confirm = "Do you want delete this user?",
               UpdateTargetId = "deleteUser"
           })</td>
     </tr>        
}
</table>
}
</div>
```

My controller is:

```
    public ActionResult DisplayUser()
    {
        List<UserDisplay> users=getAllUserInDB();
        GetAllNameFirstNameLDAP(users);
        return View(users);
    }

    public ActionResult Delete(String userName)
    {
        DeleteDB(userName);
        if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return RedirectToAction("DisplayUser");
        else
        {
            List<UserDisplay> users = getAllUserInDB();
            GetAllNameFirstNameLDAP(users);
            return PartialView("DisplayUser",users);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why it not working, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UpdateTargetId = "deleteUser"` means to refresh a DOM element with `id="deleteUser"`. You don't have such element.

You have:

```
<div class="deleteUser">
```

which is not the same as:

```
<div id="deleteUser">
```

So replace the class with id and your table should refresh normally.